# Building Ionic app for Android on Linux fails with exit code 2: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME'

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, build, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a default example app on Linux/Ubuntu 14.04 for Android.

I get a standard error message when doing **sudo ionic build android**:

> *Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.*

*(see full log down below)*

But if I do

> **echo $ANDROID_HOME && echo $JAVA_HOME && echo $ANT_HOME**
>
> > /home/user3123726/Android/Sdk
> >
> > /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
> >
> > /usr/bin/ant

And command android and cordova are also available.

- Android SDK is installed with all platform targets currently available (plus Android SDK Tools,Platform-Tools and Build tools)
- npm 3.3.9 and Node 4.2.2 is installed
- Cordova 5.3.3 was installed via npm
- Ionic 1.7.7 was installed via npm
- Apache Ant 1.9.3

ANDROID_HOME also defined on .bashrc:

> export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user3123726/Android/Sdk
>
> export PATH=${PATH}:/home/user3123726/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/user3123726/Android/Sdk/tools

I have no idea what is the reason that the build process fails. Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Here full log of ionic project creation (basically create,add platform and build):

> **ionic start myApp tabs**
>
> > Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
> >
> > [=============================]  100%  0.0s
> >
> > Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/archive/master.zip
> >
> > [=============================]  100%  0.0s
> >
> > Updated the hooks
> >     directory to have execute permissions Update Config.xml Initializing
> >     cordova project
> >
> > Your Ionic project is ready to go! Some quick tips: [... shortened]
>
> **cd myApp**
>
> **sudo ionic platform add android**
>
> > Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
> >
> > Downloading Default Ionic Resources
> >
> > Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-default-resources/archive/master.zip
> >
> > [=============================]  100%  0.0s
> >
> > Done adding default Ionic resources
> >
> > Adding icons for platform: android
> >
> > Adding android project...
> >
> > Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
> >
> > Path: platforms/android
> >
> > Package: com.ionicframework.myapp809922
> >
> > Name: myApp
> >
> > Activity: MainActivity
> >
> > Android target: android-22
> >
> > Copying template files...
> >
> > Android project created with cordova-android@4.1.1
> >
> > Running command: 
> >     /home/user3123726/testing/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/user3123726/testing/myApp
> >
> > add to body class: platform-android
> >
> > Saving platform to package.json file
> >
> > **sudo ionic build android**
> >
> > Running command: /home/user3123726/testing/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/user3123726/testing/myApp
> >
> > add to body class: platform-android
> >
> > Running command: /home/user3123726/testing/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build
> >
> > [Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
> >
> > Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]
> >
> > ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/user3123726/testing/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
> >
> > You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
> >
> > Error: /home/user3123726/testing/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
> >
> > at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
> >
> > at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
> >
> > at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
> >
> > at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
> >
> > at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

Comment: check my answer there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196730/taking-android-home-path-error-while-building-cordova-project/31207696#31207696 to make it short : don't use sudo to build the project

Comment: thanks for the hint - so it is a permission thing... although sudo echo $ANDROID_HOME returns the correct path sudo can't access these env vars? Without sudo I get hundred of warnings that removing file failed. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it:

Was a permission problem

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /home/user3123726/.cordova
```

to give cordova the rights

and did

**ionic add platform android**

**ionic build android**

without sudo ;)

Comment: I went the long way around to be a sudo user and then export ANDROID_HOME while being in sudo. The issue for me as I suspect it was for you, is that with a sudo user the $HOME variable is actually /root which is why it doesn't work with sudo. I didn't think about the permission of .cordova to be honest. Awesome job!